# calling specific data from inside Firebase array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

so my firebase document looks like this:

[image]

So it is a list with name, imgUrl etc inside of the list. My problem right now with firebase cloud firestore, is that I just want to extract all the "name:" stuff so that I can count how many times a particular name appears.

I am retrieving the data from the document like so:

```
 const matchLikes = async () => {
       await fire.firestore()
        .collection("eventLikes")
        .doc(eventID).onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            
                //console.log("print indi event heree  " + querySnapshot.data().eventID)
              
                setLikes(querySnapshot.data().ActivityLikes)
              
            
        })
```

and I have the array in a hook to use, but i just cant figure out how to access just the "name:" stuff inside the array I have tried even doing `querySnapshot.data().ActivityLikes.name` but it fails. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore doesn't support projecting specific fields and aggregating the data. You'll have to fetch the document and then manually find count of each name. Also there you don't need an `await` before `onSnapshot`. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const matchLikes = () => {
  fire.firestore()
    .collection("eventLikes")
    .doc(eventID).onSnapshot((docSnapshot) => {
      const nameCounts = docSnapshot.data().ActivityLikes.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        acc[cur.name] = (acc[cur.name] || 0) + 1;
        return acc;
      }, {});
    
      //  setLikes(querySnapshot.data().ActivityLikes)
    })
}
```